# How to create a big image on the left side and multiplie small images on the right?

Tags: positioning

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=2\linewidth]{images/Baxter.pdf}
    \caption{External Camera Setup}
    \label{fig:baxter}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \vspace{2cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{images/FV.png}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{images/FV_depth.png}
  \caption{Front Camera}
  \label{fig:ub1}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

The above snippet is what I have written. The image Baxter.pdf is on the left and the other images(Fv.png and FV_depth.png) on the right are small but do not get positioned correctly. They overlie on the Baxter.pdf which is an image in itself.

I would like something like this
[image: Left is a big image, and right side is multiplle smaller images]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. There are tons of possibilities, you could put them in a tabular/array, work with Ti*k*Z etc. Hard to be more specific because you do not disclose the document class you are using.

Comment: @marmot I am sorry, I am sort of new to Latex. I am using `\documentclass{article}` Is there anything I could refer to to make it tablular

Comment: I think that `2` in `\includegraphics[width=2\linewidth]{images/Baxter.pdf}` is the culprit. It makes the figure overshoot. Use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/Baxter.pdf}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can just typeset the well-resized small figures one-by-one, line-by-line.

## Source

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\fig}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{A Big Figures}
        \label{fig:baxter}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \fig \fig \fig \\[-\lineskip]
        \fig \fig \fig \\[-\lineskip]
        \fig \fig \fig \\[-\lineskip]
        \fig \fig \fig 
        \caption{Several Small Figures}
        \label{fig:ub1}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: output]

Notes:

1. The above example use dummy image `example-image` from package `mwe`.
2. Specific widths of `subfigure`s and figures is designed to let the height of big fig equals to 4 times of the height of small fig.
3. To manage vertical white space between lines of figures, you can add vertical space using `\\[<dimen>]`. In the example, `-\lineskip` is inserted to kill vertical spaces just right.
4. Take care of the space and/or newline symbols between figure-inserting commands.

```latex
% newline symbol acts as a space symbol, therefore produces space
\includegraphics{example-image}
\includegraphics{example-image}

% percent symbol comments out the newline symbol
\includegraphics{example-image}%
\includegraphics{example-image}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{images/Baxter.pdf}
    \caption{External Camera Setup}
    \label{fig:baxter}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hspace{\fill}
  \begin{subfigure}{.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{images/FV.png}%
    \hspace{\fill}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{images/FV_depth.png}
    \caption{Front Camera}
    \label{fig:ub1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Overall figure caption}
  \label{fig:overall}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```